# How to use Material-table with react 18?

Tags: reactjs

Hello I was looking for a react table library, supporting some features like render crud rows exporting validation etc...
I found **[Material-table](https://material-table.com/#/docs/install)** package.
The problem here is that material-table isn't compatible with react 18.

I got that Error
[image]

I tried --legacy-peer-dets but I got more compatible issues with the other react packages.
**Does anyone use material-table with react 18 without problems or can you suggest better react table package?**
any advice with be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to this problem was to downgrade React and React-DOM to version 17.0.2. I chose this approach because my project was still in its early stages and this previous version was compatible with material-table.

This way, I managed to resolve the incompatibility issue with React 18.2.0. It is worth noting that this solution may not be suitable if you are using other libraries or dependencies that specifically require React 18.

An alternative you can consider is to use the table from the Material-UI library. This library offers a variety of components for React, including tables. [MUI - React Table](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/)